# Object-like macro with "global\\.."

Tags: c++, macros

I have encountered following situation in one of C++ codes and I am having difficulties finding out what it stands for:

```
#define NAME "global\\FILENAME"
```

As much as I could have guessed, this defines some string holding path to a file. I am not however sure what `global` is there for.

Thanks

Comment: Probably the file resides in a directory named `global`.

Comment: It applies to Windows kernel object names, they live in a namespace.  Programs run in a *session*, each session has its own namespace.  That keeps them isolated from other sessions and they can't see each others kernel objects.  Most notably for a service, they run in the isolated session 0.  If you need to make such a kernel object visible across sessions then you have to put it in the global namespace.  You do so by prefixing its name with `"Global\\"`  FILENAME does not leave much of a guess, probably a badly chosen name for a shared memory object, aka "memory mapped file".